# Программное позиционирование элемента

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть окно, на которое добавляется QHBoxLayout:
Суть вопроса - необходимо программно, посредством кода - выровнять элемент `QLineEdit* searchLine;` - в компоновщике `QHBoxLayout`.

Уточнение: изначально, через дизайнер форм  - компоновщик не добавлялся, т.е просто, полностью пустая форма, на которую нужно програмно все добавлять и выравнивать.

.h файл:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QHBoxLayout* mainLayout;
    QLineEdit* searchLine;
//    QSpacerItem* LeftSerchSpacer;
//    QSpacerItem* RightSerchSpacer;
};
```

**Что уже пробовал делать:**

.cpp файл:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    searchLine = new QLineEdit(this);
```

**Пытался выровнять весь Layout:**

```
 mainLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
```

**Пытался добавлять "распорки":**

```
// LeftSerchSpacer = new QSpacerItem(2000,10);
// RightSerchSpacer = new QSpacerItem(*LeftSerchSpacer);    
// mainLayout->addItem(LeftSerchSpacer);
```

**Добавлять пустое пространство:**

```
// mainLayout->addSpacing(this->width()/2);
// mainLayout->setSpacing(this->width()/2);
// mainLayout->setMargin(this->width()/2);
// mainLayout->addStretch(100);
```

**Обращаться к конкретному виджету и выравнивать его:**

**При добавлении:**

```
//mainLayout->addWidget(searchLine,20,Qt::AlignCenter);
```

**После добавления:**

```
mainLayout->setAlignment(searchLine,Qt::AlignVCenter);

// mainLayout->addItem(RightSerchSpacer);
// mainLayout->addSpacing(100);
//  mainLayout->addWidget(searchLine);

    this->setLayout(mainLayout);
    searchLine->setVisible(true);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

- ни один, их приведенных вариантов для выравнивания элемента - не сработал.

P.S - не предлагать использовать конструктор форм. Проект - учебный, с целью освоения создания и компоновки элементов интерфейса посредством написания кода. Я знаю, что на реальных проектах - таким, никто не страдает.

UPD:
Попробовал варианты из ответов:

```
mainLayout->addStretch();
mainLayout->addWidget(searchLine);
mainLayout->addStretch();
```

и

```
mainLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
searchLine->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
mainLayout->addWidget(searchLine);
mainLayout->setAlignment(searchLine,Qt::AlignVCenter);
```

- оба не дали эффекта.

Вот, как выглядит проблемная форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(отметил красным, где примерно должен быть виджет QLineEdit)

Comment: Как его надо выравнивать?

Comment: По центру формы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Создание и заполнение горизонтального лейаута
    QHBoxLayout* hlay = new QHBoxLayout();

    // Левый спейсер (давит на QLineEdit слева)
    hlay->addItem(new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding));
    // Сам QLineEdit - будет в центре, обещаю
    hlay->addWidget(new QLineEdit());
    // Правый спейсер
    hlay->addItem(new QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding));

    // Создание вертикального лейаута
    QVBoxLayout* vlay = new QVBoxLayout(this->centralWidget());

    // Верхний виджет, на котором располагается hlay, на котором QLineEdit
    QWidget* wTop = new QWidget();
    wTop->setLayout(hlay);

    // Нижний виджет, который подпирает верхний
    QWidget* wBottom = new QWidget();    
    wBottom->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    // добавление виджетов в вертикальный лейаут
    vlay->addWidget(wTop);
    vlay->addWidget(wBottom);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Знаю, что обычно просят не засорять комментарии, но огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что ты хочешь сделать нечто такое:

```
searchLine = new QLineEdit(this);
mainLayout->addStretch();
mainLayout->addWidget(searchLine);
mainLayout->addStretch();
```

Comment: К сожалению, не дало эффекта.

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

auto layout = new  QHBoxLayout(ui); 
// Это эквивалентно
// auto layout = new  QHBoxLayout
// ui->setLayout(layout)

auto widget = new QLineEdit(this);
widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
layout->addWidget(widget);
layout->setAlignment(widget, Qt::AlignVCenter);
```

Причем при такой постановке ui вообще не нужен, можно установить layout напрямую на пустой QWidget, и установить его в окно через `setCentralWidget`

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло

Comment: И, кстати, у меня вариант с конструктором  QHBoxLayout(ui) - вообще выдает ошибку